# Add a conditional to a JPQL BETWEEN statement

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, backend

I have a query in my entity class and am using JPA annotations. My BETWEEN statement returns results, but I cannot seem to tag on this conditional "WHERE e.feature = :feature" which references a String value in another table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
public class Events implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long eventsPk;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERS")
    private Users user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FEATURES")
    private Features feature;
    @Column(name = "TIME_OF_ENTRY", unique = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timeOfEntry;
...
}
```

In my BusinessObject class I have this query where em is the EntityManager instance:

```
public class EventsBusinessObject {
    private static org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventsBusinessObject.class);
    public static List<Events> getEventsBetweenDates(EntityManager em, Date startDate, Date endDate, String feature) {
        List<Events> events = null;
        try {
            events = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE e.timeOfEntry 
                     BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate 
                     AND SELECT Feature f FROM Features WHERE f.feature = :feature")
                    .setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                    .setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                    .setParameter("feature", feature)
                    .getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            logger.error("NoResultException for EventsBusinessObject.getEventsBetweenDates");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("unknown exception for EventsBusinessObject.getEventsBetweenDates");
        }
        return events;
    }//end getEventsBetweenDates method
```

The following JPQL returns entries fine:

```
SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE e.timeOfEntry BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

It is when I start trying to add the Feature conditional that I am not getting any results from the database:

```
> @NamedQuery(name = "Events.getEventsBetweenDates", query = "SELECT e
> from Events e WHERE e.timeOfEntry BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate" AND
> e.feature = :feature)
```

This query was the one that returns the NullPointerException when called from the BusinessObject query method:

```
SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE e.timeOfEntry BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND e.feature = :feature
```

any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Define "can't get the query to work"...are you getting an exception or is it just not returning the correct results? Also, in your example, you're not using the named query. Use `em.createNamedQuery("Events.getEventsBetweenDates")`

Comment: Okay, please include the exception stack trace and indicate where in your code the exception is being thrown.

Comment: doing em.createNamedQuery hasn't ever worked for me in the past. I guess these aren't named queries then. I'll stick to calling them JPQL queries then

Comment: And by not working, I mean that I'm getting a NullPointerException exception
That null pointer exception came about at the part of my code that tried to read the results from the EventsBusinessObject.getEventsBetweenDates() method

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at ....controller.Main.main(Main.java:50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dawned on me that I could utilize the auto-complete functionality of Netbeans to help me out. When doing a @NamedQuery() in an entity class, you can do the control+spacebar shortcut to have Netbeans tell you what options are syntactically correct.

This is the query that worked for me:

```
    events = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE e.feature.name = :featureName AND e.timeOfEntry BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
            .setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            .setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            .setParameter("featureName", featureName)
            .getResultList();
```